# Merge subarrays into single one and remove duplicates if they have same id using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something', '1234563212']]
```

And I want to merge the subarrays that have same id and get this result:

```
array = [[1, 'Something', '123456321'], [2, 'Something, Something', '123456321, 1234563212']]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.group_by(&:first).map do |id, records|
  names  = records.map(&:second).join(', ')
  values = records.map(&:last).join(', ')

  [id, names, values]
end
```

---

As you asked the reversed question recently, I suggest you to read the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html), [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html), [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Hash.html) and [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html) documentations. It will give you an instant boost in expressiveness and understanding of how to do common tasks with Ruby.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the suggestion and for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a one-liner :

```
array.group_by(&:first).map{|i, arrays| [i] + arrays.transpose.drop(1).map{|v| v.join(', ') } }
```